# Making a tile grid in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple puzzle game in unity and I would like to make a tile map.

I have some decent knowledge in programming so I'm completly confused with this not working.

The code is as simple as this:

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tilePrefab;
    public Vector2 gridSize;

    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridSize.x; x++)
        {
            Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            for (int y = 1; y < gridSize.y; y++)
                Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, y), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

It could be that I'm tired, but this could should work!

Here is a 2D visualisation on how it should look when generated:

Ex. gridSize is set to (3,3)
1's represent the tiles

111
111
111

But here is how it looks as is:

1
1
111

Why is that? Considering it starts from the down leftmost one.

PS. I'm going to sleep now. Will be online in roughly 12 hours.

Comment: Why not use unity’s built in tile map

Comment: what would that be?

Comment: Er tilemap. It’s built into unity

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple and I feel dumb for making such a mistake.
Here is the fix:

From

for (int y = 1; y < gridSize.y; y++)
                Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, y), Quaternion.identity);

To

for (int y = 1; y < gridSize.y; y++)
                Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity);